# How to get more JSON data on scroll or while scrolling?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json

I have the following code below which returns some results when the user searches a term.
Once i get some results,I  want to add feature which will allow me to get more data when scrolling down ward?

NOTE: I dont want to use any plugin(s).

```
$(document).ready(function() {
         $("#submit").click(function (event) { // wire up this as an onclick event to the submit button.                   
                    var searchTerm = $("#search").val(); // get the user-entered search term
                    var URL = "http://api.flickr.com/services/feeds/photos_public.gne";
                    //var URL = "http://api.flickr.com/services/feeds/photos_public.gne";
                    var ID = "25053835@N03";
                    //var MYID-"84215563@N08";
                    //var tagmode="&tagmode=any";
                    //var format ="&format=json";
                    var tags="&tags="+ searchTerm;
                    var tagmode="&tagmode=any";
                    var jsonFormat = "&format=json&jsoncallback=?";                 
                    var ajaxURL= URL+"?jsoncallback=?id="+ID+tags+tagmode+jsonFormat;
                    //var ajaxURL= URL+"?"+tags+tagmode+jsonFormat;

                    $.getJSON(ajaxURL,function(data){
                    //$("h1").text(data.title);
                    //alert(data.length);

                    var photoHTML;
                     $("#photos").empty();  
                        if (data.items.length) {
                            alert(data.items.length);

                          $.each(data.items, function(i,photo) {

                            //var photoHTML = "<h4>" +photo.tags + "</h4>";
                            photoHTML = "<p>";
                            photoHTML += '<a href="' + photo.link + '">';
                            photoHTML += '<img src="' + photo.media.m + '" alt="' + photo.media.m + '" title="' + photo.media.m + '"></a>';
                            photoHTML = "</p>";
                            $('#photos').append(photoHTML).fadeIn(200);
                                                      });

                        } else {
                            alert(data.items.length);   
                             photoHTML = "<h2> No Results</h2>";
                             $('#photos').append(photoHTML).fadeIn(200);
                        }
                         //$('#photos').append(photoHTML).fadeIn(200);

                 });



            });         
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can also bind scroll event using jquery:

Put your whole code into a function:

```
function myfun(){
//-- you code
}
```

and call `myfun()` from both event:

on click event-

```
 $("#submit").click(function (event) {
     myfun();
 });
```

on scroll event -

```
 $("#yourSelector").scroll(function(){
       myfun();
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use the jquery .scroll() method. You have two options, save all data when page loads then display as user scrolls OR make ajax request every time there is a scroll down request.

```
$("#yourSelector").on('scroll', function(){
    // do stuff
});
```

or simply using the shortcut:

```
$("#yourSelector").scroll(function(){
   // do stuff
});
```

I hope this helps!

Here is a link to jquery scroll api to know about the options (such as specifying scroll DOWN): http://api.jquery.com/scroll/